# Locating calling code when it is not listed in the call stack (to solve null reference exception)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, xaf

I have the following error

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.v22.1
  StackTrace:
   at DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataItem.UpdateDefaultString(IEFCoreWeakReference objectForUpdate, EntityEntry entityEntry, Object key) in DevExpress.Persistent\DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore\AuditTrail\AuditDataItem.cs:line 99
```

The complete call stack is

> DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataItem.UpdateDefaultString(DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.IEFCoreWeakReference objectForUpdate, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry entityEntry, object key) Line 99    C#
> DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataItem.UpdatePersistentData(System.Collections.Generic.List<DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.IEFCoreWeakReference> weakReferences) Line 63 C#
> DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataContainer.AttachAuditData(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext dbContext) Line 73  C#
> DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditDataContainer.SaveAuditData(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext dbContext) Line 59    C#
> DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore.AuditTrail.AuditTrailService.AuditedDbContext_SavedChanges(object sender, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SavedChangesEventArgs e) Line 142 C#
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess) Line 515  C#
> MyApp.Module.dll!MyApp.Module.BusinessObjects.JobTalkDbContext.SaveChanges() Line 466   C#
> DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore.EFCoreObjectSpace.DoCommit() Line 343   C#
> DevExpress.EntityFrameworkCore.Security.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.EntityFrameworkCore.Security.SecuredEFCoreObjectSpace.DoCommit() Line 142  C#
> DevExpress.ExpressApp.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.BaseObjectSpace.CommitChanges() Line 370  C#
> MyApp.Module.Win.dll!MyApp.Module.Win.Features.PurchFeature.POStateViewController.actPurchStateMenu_Execute(object sender, DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.SingleChoiceActionExecuteEventArgs args) Line 200  C#
> DevExpress.ExpressApp.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBase.ExecuteCore(System.Delegate handler, DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ActionBaseEventArgs eventArgs) Line 289 C#
> DevExpress.ExpressApp.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.SingleChoiceAction.DoExecute(DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.ChoiceActionItem selectedItem) Line 111    C#
> DevExpress.ExpressApp.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Templates.ActionControls.Binding.SingleChoiceActionBinding.ActionControl_Execute(object sender, DevExpress.ExpressApp.Templates.ActionControls.SingleChoiceActionControlExecuteEventArgs e) Line 89   C#
> DevExpress.XtraBars.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem.OnClick(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink link) Line 1219   C#
> DevExpress.XtraBars.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink.OnLinkClick() Line 1222   C#
> DevExpress.XtraBars.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItemLink.OnLinkAction(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarLinkAction action, object actionArgs) Line 781  C#
> DevExpress.XtraBars.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarSelectionInfo.UnPressLink(DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink link) Line 836  C#
> DevExpress.XtraBars.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomLinksControl.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) Line 1173    C#
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks) Line 12439    C#
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 13229    C#
> DevExpress.Utils.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 149  C#
> DevExpress.XtraBars.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg) Line 414 C#
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 68 C#
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 122  C#
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, Interop.User32.WM msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Line 370 C#
> [Native to Managed Transition]
> [Managed to Native Transition]
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.UIntPtr dwComponentID, Interop.Mso.msoloop uReason, void* pvLoopData) Line 346  C#
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Interop.Mso.msoloop reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Line 1117  C#
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Interop.Mso.msoloop reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Line 981    C#
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run() Line 1181   C#
> DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.v22.1.dll!DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinApplication.Start() Line 834   C#
> MyApp.Win.dll!MyApp.Win.Program.Main() Line 112 C#

In Options Debugging I have unchecked "Enable Just My Code" and I have enabled Symbols from DevExpress , Nuget and Microsoft

But I do not see where UpdateDefaultString gets called.
How do I find that so that I can discover the cause of the Null Reference Exception?

[image: Enabled Symbols]

I tried using Visual Studio to look at the code in AuditTrailService.SaveAuditData but get a message "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret."
[image: Cannot Navigate]

Am I missing a symbol file perhaps?
I am using VS2022 17.2.6

[Update]

I think the actual error may have been to do with an incorrect Foreign Key in that the actual Key contained incorrect data ( zero when it should have been null ). The relationship was not enforced by the database.

Bu putting a break on line 63 I could see that AuditTrialService.GetKeyAsObject is called

[image: UpdatePersistentData]

[image: GetKeyAsObject]

Why can't I step into Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalClrEntityEntry ?

Hovering over Type entityType I see

> entityType = {Name = Inspecting the state of an object in the debuggee
> of type System.Type is not supported in this context. FullName =
> Inspecting the state of an object in the debuggee of type System.Type
> is not supported in this context.}

Comment: From the stack trace, I would say "AuditDataItem.UpdatePersistentData(..) Line 63", though the stack trace won't show any small methods that have been inlined.

Comment: The code is inside AuditedObjectEntry which is of type EntityEntry  but why cant I navigate into EntityEntry